# Possible to store getvalue() from FTP and store into dataframe Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, ftp

I'm trying to see if I can store .txt files directly from an FTP and turning it into a **single concatenated** dataframe variable without saving each file on my local drive.

My method of doing this right now looks like this:

```
#import packages

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import os, io
import re
import ftplib
from ftplib import *
from ftplib import FTP
from io import StringIO, BytesIO

ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov') # enter the main page

ftp.login() # log in to archive

# directory for monthly data
ftp.cwd('htdocs/products/analysis_monitoring/cdus/degree_days/archives/Heating degree Days/monthly states/2018')

filenames_monthly = ftp.nlst() # get list of filenames in archive

#grab files wanted from a list of files already on local machine
filenames_wanted_monthly = list(set(filenames_monthly).intersection(date_list_monthly)) # get list of unobtained dates

for file_month in filenames_wanted_monthly:
    r = BytesIO()
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ file_month, r.write)
    df_list.append(r.getvalue().decode('utf-8'))
    print(r.getvalue())
```

When I `print` the values I get the text I'm looking for but in an unaggregated and messy form:

```
b' \n              HEATING DEGREE DAY DATA MONTHLY SUMMARY\n     POPULATION-WEIGHTED STATE,REGIONAL,AND NATIONAL AVERAGES\n              CLIMATE PREDICTION CENTER-NCEP-NWS-NOAA\n \n                     MONTHLY DATA FOR OCT 2018\n                 ACCUMULATIONS ARE FROM JULY 1, 2018\n         -999 = NORMAL LESS THAN 100 OR RATIO INCALCULABLE\n \n   STATE         MONTH MON  MON     CUM   CUM   CUM   CUM   CUM\n                 TOTAL DEV  DEV     TOTAL DEV   DEV   DEV   DEV\n                       FROM FROM          FROM  FROM  FROM  FROM\n                       NORM L YR          NORM  L YR  NORM  L YR\n                                                      PRCT  PRCT\n  \n ALABAMA            90  -63  -28      90   -78   -48   -46   -35\n ALASKA            685 -314 -149    1436  -629  -251   -30   -15\n ARIZONA            43  -33   42      43   -40    42  -999  -999\n ARKANSAS          197   24   24     215    14    24     7    13\n CALIFORNIA         43  -76   -5      43  -126   -22   -75   -34\n COLORADO          593   20   37     721  -187   -38   -21    -5\n CONNECTICUT       399  -22  179     498   -56   137   -10    38\n DELAWARE          242  -43   94     245   -83    75   -25    44\n DISTRCT COLUMBIA  194  -11  103     195   -36    97   -16    99\n FLORIDA             3   -7  -19       3    -7   -19  -999  -999\n GEORGIA           117  -37  -18     117   -52   -39   -31   -25\n HAWAII              0    0    0       0     0     0  -999  -999\n IDAHO             535    3  -78     732  -112  -104   -13   -12\n ILLINOIS          430   35  135     529     9   107     2    25\n INDIANA           386   10   95     471   -24    45    -5    11\n IOWA
```

Appending to the list gives me a set of `str` valued lists of `size=1`.

Is there a way to store these .txt files by separating them by the `\n` tags into a single readable dataframe?

My desired output would be a dataframe with 2 columns with the first 2 values after each instance of `\n`:

```
STATE              TOTAL
ALABAMA            90
ARIZONA            43
CALIFORNIA         43
CONNECTICUT       399
.
.
```

Comment: You are showing us your current output, but it would help if you would also include your desired output. It seems like stripping space and splitting on `'\n'` would be a good place to start, but your question is difficult to answer without knowing what you actually want.

Comment: Thank you @d_kennetz. I have updated my desired output.

Comment: I'm having difficulty reproducing -- what is supposed to be the value of the variable `date_list_monthly`?

Answer (score 0):

use the StringIO to write the strings from getvalue() to a file and then read that file using pandas to get the desired dataframe

```
1. test_result = StringIO(result) # write strings to a file 

2. pd.read_csv(test_result,sep="\n") # convert to dataframe
```